# Cannot ping certain IP

Tags: networking

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64). From this machine I need to access some third-party API. They don't even have a domain name, so access is by IP only. The API is reachable, I can access it from my dev machine, and various online services can ping its IP too.

From my virtual machine I'm not able to ping this IP however. Everyhting else except this IP works fine, I can ping other IPs no problem.  My hosting provider (Hetzner) says that from their side everything looks fine. Is there anything I can do to make this IP reachable?

Comment: are you able to ping other ip's instead? if not, you might be blocking outgoing icmp traffic perhaps.

Comment: I edited my post. Everything else works fine, I can ping other IPs without any problems.

Comment: Firstly update your machine (16.04.5 was released in 2-August-2018, so your vm is at least that out-of-date), but confirm you can ping those other IPs from the VM itself.  It sounds like a problem with your HOST restricting traffic (if not the fact that your system is just months behind with updates).

Comment: I upgraded to latest 16.04, and on the other machine I even upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Cannot ping this IP from both of them. Any other IP pings just fine, there's backend running which talks to external APIs a lot. I also created blank new 18.04 VM in same data center and from it I can ping this IP. How can I check if my host restricting traffic to this ip?